# Get a list of duplicate items in a list but only from one column

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a `List<T>` where `T` has two properties:

```
public int ID { get; set;}
public decimal Amount {get; set;}
```

The original list, `results`, looks like this...

```
ID    Amount
```

---

```
 1      5.50
 2      6.50
 3      6.50
 4      7.00
```

I need to extract a new list where there are any duplicates in the Amount column.  So in this case the resulting `List<T>` would be:

```
ID    Amount
```

---

```
 2      6.60
 3      6.50
```

There are a lot of threads here that address this general question, and from them I've gotten to here:

```
var duplicateItems = results.GroupBy(r => r.Amount)
                    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key);
```

But that gets me a list that looks like this:

```
6.50
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This:

```
var duplicateItems = results.GroupBy(r => r.Amount)
                      .Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

Also gets me this:

```
6.50
```

Comment: in your example there is no any duplicate amount values

Comment: how did you get that result

Comment: I don't understand.  In the original list, there are two rows with an amount of 6.50

Comment: Just leave off the `.Select(x=>x.Key);` and you have a list of T

Comment: key # 2 is 6.60 not 6.50, thats where the confusion is coming from

Comment: Ah!  My bad!  Fixed.

Comment: Is Amount a double/float? is it calculated?beware of floating point comparisons... Try changing it to decimal..I guess it will work (assuming that there are indeed duplicates of course)

Comment: It is a decimal

Comment: Your code is correct,the problem is somewhere else.
Double check/print your values again. Try **results.Select(k => k.Amount).Distinct();** and see how many values there are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results.GroupBy(r => r.Amount).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g);
```

Tested locally, should give the desired result.

Comment: nailed it!  Thanks!!

Comment: btw... THANK YOU for actually looking at, and understanding, the results that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var duplduplicateItems cates = results.GroupBy(r => r ).SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing.

Comment: This got me a list with a single item: 6.50.

Comment: because in your list only 6.50 duplicate value. How many elements are there in your list? Are you sure there are another duplicates?

Comment: What I am looking for is a new List<T>, with both the ID and the Amount, not just the amount.  And I need a row for every duplicate, in this case, two rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
result.GroupBy(x => x.Amount).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing.

Comment: This got me 0 results

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need, I don't understand why you rejected my comment

```
var duplicateItems = results.GroupBy(r => r.Amount)
                      .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
```

Comment: This gets me a resulting list that looks like this: 6.50

Comment: It only gives me a single row with no ID

Comment: I need two rows (one for each duplicate) that are a List<T> with ID and Amount.

Comment: Sorry, was testing in LinqPad and forgot the add the SelectMany clause, Andrew Jenkins had me beat